# python 0 assigner returns none despite the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value

I have a problem in python(python 3.9 on VS Code). I'm trying to change a value in a dictionary by some conditions:

```
def getset(age):
    age['age']+=0 if age['age']>=0 else age['age'] == 0
mammad = {'name': 'mammad', 'age': -3}
mammad = getset(mammad)
print(mammad)
```

as you can see in `age['age']+=0 if age['age']>=0 else age['age'] == 0` age key has to have a value of 0 if it's lower than 0. But anyway, it changes it to none. What's the problem?

Comment: Your function doesn't *return* anything, it modifies the dict in place.

Comment: What exactly is `0 if age['age']>=0 else age['age'] == 0` supposed to do? It seems to _always_ evaluate to `0` or `False`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the `dict` after you make changes to it (you are assigning `None` from the function call when it returns *nothing*) or just call the function without assigning it to your variable since it will modify the `dict` *in-place* anyway. You can change the dictionary like this:

```
def getset(age):
    age['age'] = 0 if age['age'] < 0 else age['age']

mammad = {'name': 'mammad', 'age': -3}
# no need to 'assign' to 'mammad' again, you changed it already!
getset(mammad)
>>> print(mammad)
{'name': 'mammad', 'age': 0}
```

A function which returns nothing prints nothing (`None`).

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
>>> print(f())
None
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the age. if you don't return anything it will be None.